# Trouble finding which polygons contain which points using SP package in R

Tags: r, coordinates, geo, r-sp

I have a set of points:

```
> head(Map3)
SpatialPoints:
                   lat      long
Cincinnati OH 39.10312 -84.51202
Dayton OH     39.75895 -84.19161
Lexington KY  38.04058 -84.50372
Zanesville OH 39.94035 -82.01319
Louisville KY 38.25266 -85.75846
Columbus OH   39.96118 -82.99879
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

And a set of polygons called `shape`, which are regions in the U.S. (DMAs).

They have the same coordinate system, and I know that they overlap:

```
> proj4string(shape)
[1] "+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
>   proj4string(Map3)
[1] "+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
> bbox(Map3 )
            min       max
lat    21.30694  64.83778
long -157.85833 -68.77781
>   bbox(shape )
         min       max
x -124.73297 -66.94932
y   24.54424  49.38436
```

They also appear to have similar ranges (and the lat/long appear to be in the right order):

```
>   range(Map3@bbox)
[1] -157.85833   64.83778
>   range(shape@bbox)
[1] -124.73297   49.38436
```

But when I try to get the polygons where the points are contained, I get nothing:

```
> indices <- over(Map3,shape)
> head(indices)
              NAME PHshare Rank PUSA  DMA USTV CPHShare Hrank HTV markets marketpop Dmoney Rmoney Dpc Rpc AdsPC adrepshare fraction split
Cincinnati OH <NA>      NA   NA   NA <NA>   NA       NA    NA  NA    <NA>        NA     NA     NA  NA  NA    NA         NA       NA    NA
Dayton OH     <NA>      NA   NA   NA <NA>   NA       NA    NA  NA    <NA>        NA     NA     NA  NA  NA    NA         NA       NA    NA
Lexington KY  <NA>      NA   NA   NA <NA>   NA       NA    NA  NA    <NA>        NA     NA     NA  NA  NA    NA         NA       NA    NA
Zanesville OH <NA>      NA   NA   NA <NA>   NA       NA    NA  NA    <NA>        NA     NA     NA  NA  NA    NA         NA       NA    NA
Louisville KY <NA>      NA   NA   NA <NA>   NA       NA    NA  NA    <NA>        NA     NA     NA  NA  NA    NA         NA       NA    NA
Columbus OH   <NA>      NA   NA   NA <NA>   NA       NA    NA  NA    <NA>        NA     NA     NA  NA  NA    NA         NA       NA    NA
```

Not sure what the problem is- all I want is to find out which regions contain the points.

If the problem is the order of the lat/long, how would I reverse this?

Here is the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0fpupcaek6g6zhy/AACNVh2YknS15aWe3RtV_zW7a?dl=0)

Comment: I think you need to switch the order of Map3 and shape in the call to `over`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you specified correctly longitude to be x, and latitude to be y in your SpatialPoints ?
Your `bbox` outputs are not in the same order, so I guess this is the mistake.

Edit:
The bbox of your point data is not in the right order. You should import your csv file as is:

```
library(sp)

Map3 <- read.csv("stackdata/points.csv")
coordinates(Map3) <- ~lon+lat

bbox(Map3)
```

If you plot your points over your shapefile, you should see if they overlay or not.

```
plot(shape)
points(Map3)
```

Comment: I am not sure that that is the mistake, as checking range(Map3@bbox) and range(shape@bbox) show them in the same order.

Comment: When you plot your data, are they overlapping ? Could you provide your data here so that we can try ourselves ?

Comment: When you share a shapefile, you need to include all the 4 files and not only the `.shp`: dbf, shp, shx, prj. Otherwise, I cannot open it. However, it seems, as I said, that you did not specified the longitude and latitude correctly for your points data. Look at my edit in my answer. Did you plot your data before the overlay ? If this still does not work, please add your complete R-code, with reading data and plot.

Comment: This works. The key was `coordinates(Map3) <- ~lon+lat`   Thank you very much.